# Boostrap with "justified-nav.css" doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to build an HTML webpage that uses the [bootstrap justified-nav.css style](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css) and bootstrap.min.css as core.

When I open index.html it doesn't work properly and displays only a few of the justified-nav.css attributes. I think the problem has to do with the names of the files. I tried changing to boostrap.min and the file type to .CSS but it still doesn't work. How do I solve this?

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Computer Solutions</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
           Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->
      <div class="masthead">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Computer Solutions</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <!-- Jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://techguystaging.com/files/computer-icon.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Computer Solutions</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Safari bug warning!</h2>
          <p class="text-danger">As of v9.1.2, Safari exhibits a bug in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing.</p>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Site footer -->
      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

/* Main marketing message and sign up button */
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  padding: 14px 24px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

/* Customize the nav-justified links to be fill the entire space of the .navbar */

.nav-justified {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav-justified > li > a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5e5e5; /* Old browsers */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#e5e5e5));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  background-repeat: repeat-x; /* Repeat the gradient */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
.nav-justified > .active > a,
.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
          box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.nav-justified > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-justified {
    max-height: 52px;
  }
  .nav-justified > li > a {
    border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  .nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  }
  .nav-justified > li:last-child > a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  }
}

/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .masthead,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

**My folder**
[image]

Comment: Its working fine check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/qaBzjp) link

Comment: Oh? How come it works on codepen but not on my chrome webpage? That is very weird.. Do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: Inspect your code in browser with inspect tool and check if your css is loading or not

Comment: How do I do that? I'm very new to this I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Press F12 and look for css file in head tag

Comment: Okay I did that, I right clicked on style.css and clicked "open in new tab" and it opened fine. When I right clicked on bootstrap.min.css and tried to open in a new tab it said that the file doesn't exist although as you can see it does exist in the folder..

Comment: So that means you have to give the right path to bootstrap file or declaration of file is incorrect.

Comment: Okay so as you said I tried to change a few things. First my index.html used bootstrap.min.css but its actually a .map file so I changed to bootstrap.min.css.map, then when I F12ed and opened it in a new tab it did show the bootrap.min.css file correctly, but still didn't work. I changed the bootstrap.min to a CSS file and used bootstrap.min.css and again, didn't work, but did open the correct file in a new tab after F12. It STILL doesn't work doesn't matter what way I tried.

Comment: replace the bootstrap css link with this <link href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css " rel="stylesheet">

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked, can you tell me what went wrong there so I don't make that mistake again?

Comment: I think the file name is the issue because it should display the type CSS in your folder structure. Glad to know that your problem is resolved.. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solution**

The problem had to do with the bootstrap script link I was using. For some reason it was defected and changing it to a different source solved the problem. The bootstrap source that worked for me was:

```
<link href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.cs‌​s"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Credit is given to Jyoti Pathania for the assistance.